# io.smallrye.mutiny.TimeoutException after adding quarkus.vault. to application.propperties

Tags: java, quarkus, hashicorp-vault, smallrye

I'm writing my first bigger Quarkus Applications. Using maven and Java 11, on Windows.

At the moment, I'm trying to make it more secure. I Implemented Authentication using smallrey jwt and that worked fine. Now I'm trying to secure my application.properties by saving the secrets and keys inside a Hashicrop Vault.

I followed [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/vault) guide to implement this. It´s working fine until the compilation part. If I try to compile after adding these lines to my application.property

```
# vault url
quarkus.vault.url=http://localhost:8200
quarkus.vault.kv-secret-engine-version=2
# vault authentication
quarkus.vault.authentication.client-token=xxx
# path within the kv secret 
quarkus.vault.secret-config-kv-path=test
```

And try to compile it wit mvn quarkus:dev. I get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to start application (with profile dev)
io.smallrye.mutiny.TimeoutException
    at  
io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait.await(UniBlockingAwait.java:58)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.atMost(UniAwait.java:61)
    at 
io.quarkus.vault.runtime.client.VertxVaultClient.exec(VertxVaultClient.java:161)
    at 
io.quarkus.vault.runtime.client.VertxVaultClient.exec(VertxVaultClient.java:146)
    at 
io.quarkus.vault.runtime.client.VertxVaultClient.get(VertxVaultClient.java:127)
```

[Link to the complete log](https://pastebin.com/JBwXvYTJ). I'm a bit lost and can't read anything meaningful out of the error log, so I'm not sure where to look for the wrong configuration.

I'm not trying to access anything inside the vault at the moment.

Comment: Did you possibly try to increase the read timeout of your Vault client: `quarkus.vault.read-timeout=10S`

Usually should not be the case for local setup, but if you reach to this point, it means that you've established the connection

Comment: No, of course not, that would be way too simple. Thanks a lot, that solved the problem.